# Статистическое выражение нельзя использовать в списке SET инструкции UPDATE

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Помогите пожалуйста. 
Есть данный запрос "Update Table_1 set Fx = (id/(MAX(id)+1))" , Где нужно высчитать столбец Fx, который равен id/"количество_строк_либо_максимальное_значение_id"+1) Помогите, как это сделать. Пишет данную ошибку Статистическое выражение нельзя использовать в списке SET инструкции UPDATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
Update Table_1 set Fx = id/(select MAX(id)+1 from Table_1)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Для простого "пожалуйста" не хватает символов. :-)